# Программа складывающая значения в списке словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dict

Есть некий список словарей:

```
spis_dict = [
    {'item':'item1','amount':400},
    {'item':'item2','amount':300},
    {'item':'item1','amount':750}
]
```

Как сложить значения и вывести, например:

```
Counter({'item1':1150,'item2':300})
```

Answer (score 1):

Существует более элегантное решение:

```
spis_dict = [
    {'item': 'item1', 'amount': 400},
    {'item': 'item2', 'amount': 300},
    {'item': 'item3', 'amount': 100},
    {'item': 'item1', 'amount': 750},
    {'item': 'item2', 'amount': 50},
    {'item': 'item2', 'amount': 65}
]

rez = {}
for it in spis_dict:
    item = it['item']
    amount = it['amount']
    rez[item] = rez.setdefault(item, 0) + amount
    
print(f'rez = {rez}\n')
```

Здесь используется метод *setdefault()*, который делает то же самое, что и метод *get()* но если нужный элемент пока не существует в словаре, то он создаёт этот элемент с заданным ключом и значением по умолчанию.

В данном случае, в качестве значения по умолчанию используется первоначальная сумма равная нулю. А если элемент существует, то плюсум к нему.

Comment: примечательно, что в данном случае можно заменить  `setdeault`  на  `get`  , то есть:  `rez[item] = rez.get(item, 0) + amount`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
spis_dict = [
    {'item': 'item1', 'amount': 400},
    {'item': 'item2', 'amount': 300},
    {'item': 'item1', 'amount': 750}
]

rez = {}
for it in spis_dict:
    item = it['item']
    amount = it['amount']
    
    r = rez.get(item)
    if r is None:
        rez[item] = amount
    else:
        rez[item] += amount
    
print(f'rez = {rez}\n')
```